# ValueError despite try and except

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch, valueerror, except

I am using try and except to prevent ValueError, but I am still getting it, which I do not understand:

```
if ('Address' and 'Phone') in text_string:
    try:
        pos_1 = text_string.index('Address')
        pos_2 = text_string.index('Phone')
        output['address'] = text_string[pos_1+7:pos_2]
    except ValueError:
        output['address'] = None
```

I am getting ValueError here:

```
 pos_1 = text_string.index('Address')
```

but since I have filtered through if clause, I should not be getting the ValueError message?

Comment: try `if 'Address' in text_string and 'Phone' in text_string:`

Answer (score 0):

Though [Nick's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick) comment would already solve the issue, but it would be helpful for the newcomers for the reason behind.

Okay, so the problem here is with the initial `if` statement.

`('Address' and 'Phone') in text_string` is equivalent to `'Phone' in text_string` because, here, a non empty string is logically `True` and it's `and` with another string, say `s2`, will result in `s2`.

So, here `('Address' and 'Phone')` is same as just `'Phone'` and hence you are just checking for `'Phone'`'s availability in `text_string` and thus that `Value Error`.

Hence the code should be,

```
if 'Address' in text_string and 'Phone' in text_string:
    try:
        pos_1 = text_string.index('Address')
        pos_2 = text_string.index('Phone')
        output['address'] = text_string[pos_1+7:pos_2]
    except ValueError:
        output['address'] = None
```